# Put a link on a div without touching the html

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I can't change the HTML to add an `<a>`-tag, but can I put a link on the div with JavaScript only?

```
<div class="some-class">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't change the html with jquery?

Comment: Add a click handler to it: http://api.jquery.com/click. Although you should note this is a violation of accessibility guidelines

Comment: I can use jQuery, I just can't access the HTML file.

Comment: In that case you could create the `a` element with jQuery

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/ should do what you want

Comment: That's interesting, I'll try that thank you

Comment: All solutions so far don't work. Maybe because it's a flipbox ... so the div turns around on mouseover (jQuery event) / changes CSS class. I tried to address the CSS class the div has on hover but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) to achieve what you want:

```
$(".some-class").wrapInner("<a href='www.google.dk'></a>");
```

It will convert your

```
<div class="some-class">
  Some content
</div>
```

into

```
<div class="some-class">
  <a href="www.google.dk">
    Some content
  </a>
</div>
```

**demo**

```js
$(".some-class").wrapInner("<a href='www.google.dk'></a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the div with jQuery

```
jQuery('.some-class').wrap('<a href="#test"></a>');
```

And you'll get

```
<a href="#test"><div class="some-class">Some content</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to append an anchor element to Div with class "some-class"

```
  $('div.some-class').append('<a href="#"></a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

paste your target url in window.open(url) function.it will not insert anything to your html code.

```
<head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="some-class">Some content</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.some-class').click(function(){
   window.open("https://#");
});

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="some-class">
  </div>

  <script>
    var data = "<a href='#'>Link </a>";
    document.getElementById('some-class').innerHTML += data;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```